# Why does UTF-8 use more than one byte to represent some characters?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I recently went through an [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/do-you-know-your-character-encodings/) on Character Encoding. I've a concern on a certain point mentioned there.

In the first figure, the author shows the characters, their code points in various character sets and how they are encoded in various encoding formats.
For example the code point of é is `E9`. 
In `ISO-8859-1` encoding it is represented as `E9`.
In `UTF-16` it is represented as `00 E9`.
But in `UTF-8` it is represented using 2 bytes, `C3 A9`.

My question is why is this required? It can be represented with 1 byte. Why are two bytes used? Can you please let me know?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) uses the 2 high bits (bit 6 and bit 7) to indicate if there are any more bytes: Only the low 6 bits are used for the actual character data. That means that any character over `7F` requires (at least) 2 bytes.

Comment: <pendantic>For codepoints under \x80, the last _seven_ bits hold character data.  For continuation bytes, 6 bits are used.  For leading bytes of a multibyte encoding, 5 or 4 bits are used.</pendantic>

Comment: Thanks Bohemian. That did clarify my query.

Comment: The genius of utf-8, is that by examining the two high bits you can determine if you are at the beginning or middle of a character. This was a problem that plagued earlier attempts at "wide" character sets; when you substring to the middle of a string you did not know if byte was the start or middle of a character, or, where "shift to wide"/"shift to 8 bit" encoding was in place what was the last shift character.

Answer (score 14):

A single byte can hold one of only 256 different values.

This means that an encoding that represents each character as a single byte, such as ISO-8859-1, cannot encode more than 256 different characters. This is why you can't use ISO-8859-1 to correctly write Arabic, or Japanese, or many other languages. There is only a limited amount of space available, and it is already used up by other characters.

UTF-8, on the other hand, needs to be capable of representing all of the millions of characters in Unicode. This makes it impossible to squeeze every single character into a single byte.

The designers of UTF-8 chose to make all of the ASCII characters (U+0000 to U+007F) representable with a single byte, and required all other characters to be stored as two or more bytes. If they had chosen to give more characters a single-byte representation, the encodings of other characters would have been longer and more complicated.

If you want a visual explanation of why bytes above `7F` don't represent the corresponding 8859-1 characters, look at the [UTF-8 coding unit table on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#Codepage_layout). You will see that every byte value outside the ASCII range either already has a meaning, or is illegal for historical reasons. There just isn't room in the table for bytes to represent their 8859-1 equivalents, and giving the bytes additional meanings would break several important properties of UTF-8.

Comment: Nice, clear, quantitative answer.  You can't represent a million characters in one byte.

Comment: I do understand that only 2^8 values can be represented using 8 bits. My question was regarding the encoding of Code Point "E9". To represent this 8 bits are sufficient. In UTF-16 it is 00E9. Where as in UTF-8 it is C3A9. Why can't they just use E9?

Comment: UTF-8 already uses the bytes beginning with `E` to represent the start of a three-byte sequence. For example the code point U+9A69 (驩) is encoded as `E9 A9 A9`. If `E9` were used to represent U+00E9 this wouldn't work, and you would have to completely redesign the encoding in a different way.

Answer (score -3):

Because many languages ​​it 2 bit encoding that is simply not enough to encode all the letters of all alphabets
Look
 2 bit encoding 00 .. FF 15 ^ 2 = 255 characters
 4 bit 0000 ... FFFF 4 ^ 15 = 50625